# Change DOM parser to not use short notation for empty nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom, transformer-model

Is there anyway to change DOM Parser Empty notation from short to long form?

I need

```
 <book></book>
```

instead of book

```
<book/>
```

We have a third party XML reader which won't work with short notation.All my XML object are DOM. What is best way going about this?

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(XMLFile);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Thanks

Comment: You should probably worry about what other parts of XML your third-party parser can't accept. Because there are probably a lot of them.

Comment: Agree with @parsifal. Your parser is non-compliant. It would be better to fix that if possible. If not you may have to postprocess your output.

Comment: Well I think thats the only one thats my only issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a guess: setting the output property to "html" on the transformer will probably do it, since html does not recognize short-circuit empty tags (I think).

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
```

NB: Not tested!

UPDATE:

I just verified that it works. This snippet:

```
String xml = "<root><a/></root>";
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

produces this output:

```
<root>
<a></a>
</root>
```

Comment: Well this didn't work Is there any way I can write Emppty element manually.

Comment: Great answer, been looking for a simple solution to this issue, Works great.

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same problem.
This is the function to get that result.

```
public static String fixClosedTag(String rawXml){

    LinkedList<String[]> listTags = new LinkedList<String[]>(); 
    String splittato[] =  rawXml.split("<");

    String prettyXML="";

    int counter = 0;
    for(int x=0;x<splittato.length;x++){
        String tmpStr = splittato[x];
        int indiceEnd = tmpStr.indexOf("/>");
        if(indiceEnd>-1){
            String nameTag = tmpStr.substring(0, (indiceEnd));
            String oldTag = "<"+ nameTag +"/>";
            String newTag = "<"+ nameTag +"></"+ nameTag +">";
            String tag[]=new String [2];
            tag[0] = oldTag;
            tag[1] = newTag;
            listTags.add(tag);
        }
    }
    prettyXML = rawXml;

    for(int y=0;y<listTags.size();y++){
        String el[] = listTags.get(y);

        prettyXML = prettyXML.replaceAll(el[0],el[1]);
    }

    return prettyXML;
}
```